# if $\sum f_n(x)$ uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$, then there is {$M_n$}$>0$ so that for all $x\in\mathbb R$ $|f(x)|<M_n$ and $\sum M_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> true or false: if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on 
>   $\mathbb R$, then there is {$M_n$}$>0$ so that for all $x\in\mathbb R$
>   $|f(x)|<M_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty M_n$ converges.

I think that it's not true, but I have no clue of how to show it.

Comment: Search "Weierstrass M-test". You are being asked of it is a necessary and sufficient condition for uniform convergence.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I know Weierstrass M-test, this is the  kind of the opposite the the test.  And as I understand, the test doesn't say something about this

Comment: Of course, that's why I recommended a literature search or an internet search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

A classical example: the series 
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\sin nx}{n}$$ converges uniformly on any interval
$[\delta, 2\pi - \delta ]$, if $\delta > 0$. However, the convergences is not normal.

$\bf{Added:}$ The example of @Wojowu: $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is much simpler. The point is: convergence does not imply abosolute convergence.

Consider now an example of a series with positive coefficients. Consider
$f_n(x) =\frac{\delta{x, n}}{n}$, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta. The convergence is uniform, but not normal, since $\max_x( |f_n(x)|) = \frac{1}{n}$ does not give a convergent series.

Comment: A simpler example is $f_n(x)=(-1)^n/n$.

Comment: @Wojowu: yes, to the point